# Comparar dos arrays (uno multidimensional) y si encuentra coincidencia, reemplazar valor

Tags: javascript, comparaciones, array-bidimensional

Tengo el siguiente problema. Resulta que tengo dos arrays:

```
let cartonBingo = [[1, 2], [5, 7], [12, 10]];

let numbersBasketBingo = [1, 7, 10, 18, 14, 20, 4, 3, 2, 13, 5, 16, 12];
```

Esto será un juego de bingo, pongo menos números para que sea más sencillo hacerlo.

cartonBingo representa lo que la variable dice, el cartón del bingo, y tiene 3 arrays dentro porque cada uno de ellos lo represento como una línea del cartón.

Lo que yo necesito es que de numbersBasketBingo, se fije si el primer valor -en este caso el `1-` se encuentra en el arrayBingo. Si lo encuentra, que el 1 de cartónBingo me lo reemplace por una "X", como si fuese tachado. Luego, debería eliminar el 1 de numbersBasketBingo, y realizar la comprobación con el siguiente número, el 7. Cuando complete una linea, o sea uno de los arrays, debo cantar linea, y así sucesivamente hasta completar todos los números con "X" de cartonBingo.
Le estoy dando vueltas con ciclos for, for each, for of y no llego al resultado esperado con ninguno.
Quiero utilizar para reemplazar los números por "X" con Splice para que me modifique el cartonBingo, y poder ir mostrándolo por pantalla, a medida que la condición se cumple.
Espero que alguien me arroje un poco de luz sobre esto porque no llego a solucionar esto. Un saludo.

Pues lo que he intentado, entre muchas otra cosas es esto:

```
let cartonBingo = [[1, 2], [5, 7], [12, 10]]
let numbersBasketBingo = [67, 7, 10, 18, 14, 20, 4, 3, 2, 13, 5, 16, 12, 6, 8, 9, 13, 11, 15, 17, 20, 19]


function checkArraysBingo2() {
  // console.log(`PASO 1`)
  for (let i = 0; i < numbersBasketBingo.length; i++) {
    console.log(numbersBasketBingo[i]);
    for (let j = 0; j < cartonBingo[0].length; j++) {
      console.log(cartonBingo[0][j]);
      if (numbersBasketBingo[i] === cartonBingo[0][j]) {
        cartonBingo[0].splice(cartonBingo[0].indexOf(numbersBasketBingo[i]), 1, "X")
        numbersBasketBingo.shift();        
      };

    };

  };

};

checkArraysBingo2();
```

Comment: No tiene sentido. Tienes las posiciones en un array y en otro los valores. Entonces ese 1 que es el valor no tiene relación con [1,2] que es la ubicación del valor

Comment: `console.log(cartonBingo.flatMap(num => num).every(num => numbersBasketBingo.includes(num)));` No es una solución a tu problema, pero sabrás si el cartón está contenido en el bingo

Comment: Creo que entendí lo que necesitas, pero debes mostrar algún esfuerzo de tu parte en la solución. Que has intentado? Añade lo que has intentado a la pregunta.

Comment: He agregado lo que estoy intentando al código, pero estoy atascado y ya no sé qué más hacer. No tengo experiencia ni siquiera un conocimiento medio, lo intento hasta donde puedo.... Un saludo y gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asi lo puedes hacer, dejo en los comentarios la explicación del código:

```js
let cartonBingo = [[1, 2], [5, 7], [12, 10]];

let numbersBasketBingo = [67, 7, 10, 18, 14, 20, 4, 3, 2, 13, 5, 1, 16, 12, 6, 8, 9, 13, 11, 15, 17, 20, 19];

//Funcion para mirar si una fila está llena (toda marcada con X)
function isFilaLLena(fila) {
  return fila.every(num => num === "X");
}

//funcion para mirar si un carton está lleno (todo marcado con X)
function isCartonLLeno() {
  return cartonBingo.every(fila => isFilaLLena(fila))
}

//Funcion para marcar un numero con una X en el carton
function marcarEnCarton(num) {
  for(let i=0; i<cartonBingo.length; i++){ //Recorremos cada fila

    let estaLLena = isFilaLLena(cartonBingo[i]); //Revisamos si esa fila ya está llena
  
    if(estaLLena){ //si está llena no hacemos nada y pasamos a la siguiente
      continue;
    } else { //Si no está llena, marcamos los numeros con X
      cartonBingo[i] = cartonBingo[i].map(filaNum => filaNum === num ? "X" : filaNum);
      
      estaLLena = isFilaLLena(cartonBingo[i]); //Revisamos si despues de marcar está llena
      
      if(estaLLena){ //Si está llena, anunciamos que esa fila se acabó de llenar
        console.log(`LLenó la fila ${i}`); //Indice 0-based
      }
    }    
  }
  
  console.log("El cartón va así", cartonBingo); //Mostramos como va el carton
}

function jugarBingo() {
  for (num of numbersBasketBingo) { //Recorremos los numeros del bingo
  
    console.log(`Jugando #${num}`); //Anunciamos el numero que vamos a jugar

    marcarEnCarton(num); //Lo marcamos en el carton
    
    if(isCartonLLeno()){ //Si el cartón está lleno, cantamos Bingo!
      console.log("Bingo!");
      return; //y termina el ciclo
    }
  };
};

jugarBingo();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Pipe por la ayuda...

Comment: Si te sirvió la respuesta considera marcarla como aceptada para asi ayudar a la comunidad. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Ya tienes una respuesta pero igual te doy la mía, las líneas se van cantando a medida que se van completando, y los números de las numberBasketBingo (acá lo llame "tiradas") se eliminan si se encuentran en el cartón:

```
let carton = [[12,14],[2,56],[15,24],[65,71],[23,83],[96,22]];
let tiradas = [15,96,27,23,83,65,12,98,71,11,9,14,99,56];

const estaCompleta = (linea, carton) => (linea.every(elem => elem === "X")) ?  `LINEA COMPLETADA! linea ${carton.indexOf(linea)+1} del carton` : undefined;
// verifica si cierta linea del carton esta completa, si lo es devuelve un msj con el numero de linea completa, sino devuelve undefined

function filtrarHallados(tiradas){ // devuelve un array filtrando los elementos "hallado" y dejando el resto
  return tiradas.filter(elem => elem !== "hallado");
}

function jugar(tiradas,carton){
  for(const tirada of tiradas)
    for(const linea of carton)
      if(linea.includes(tirada)){ // si la linea incluye la tirada
        linea[linea.indexOf(tirada)] = "X"; // cambio el elemento de la linea por una X
        tiradas[tiradas.indexOf(tirada)] = "hallado"; // los elementos de tiradas que se hayan encontrado en el carton los marcamos como "hallados" para eliminarlos despues, eliminarlos en este punto nos romperia el for por eso lo hago despues
        let hayLinea = estaCompleta(linea, carton); // guardo resultado de la funcion
        if(hayLinea!==undefined) console.log(hayLinea); // si no es undefined imprime el msj
      }
}

jugar(tiradas,carton);
tiradas = filtrarHallados(tiradas)
console.log(carton)
console.log(tiradas)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda ElFuturo Llego!!!!